# Different diff operations on different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do different diff() manipulation on different columns in a pandas dataframe. Below is an example of using if-statement in a lambda function to take diff(1) on col1 and diff(2) on col2.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[32,42,54,62,76,76,87,98,122,111,132,134,134,156],
                    'col2':[32,58,59,63,65,72,95,100,102,101,232,234,234,256]})

data.apply(lambda x: x.diff(1) if x.name=='col1' else x.diff(2))
```

I was first thinking about a solution with a dictionary, similar to the [agg function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html). That would be easier when there is more than two columns. Does anyone have some handy methods on how to make different diff() operations on different columns?

Comment: You could just use assign and overwrite the existing columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all operation return Series with same size like original column like `diff` or `cumsum` is possible use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
df = data.agg({'col1':lambda x: x.diff(), 'col2':lambda x: x.diff(2)})
print (df)
    col1   col2
0    NaN    NaN
1   10.0    NaN
2   12.0   27.0
3    8.0    5.0
4   14.0    6.0
5    0.0    9.0
6   11.0   30.0
7   11.0   28.0
8   24.0    7.0
9  -11.0    1.0
10  21.0  130.0
11   2.0  133.0
12   0.0    2.0
13  22.0   22.0
```

---

```
df = data.agg({'col1':lambda x: x.diff(), 'col2':'mean'})
print (df)
```

> ValueError: cannot perform both aggregation and transformation operations simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

One easy option could be to use a dictionary to hold the periods:

```
periods = {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}

data.apply(lambda c: c.diff(periods[c.name]))
```

output:

```
    col1   col2
0    NaN    NaN
1   10.0    NaN
2   12.0   27.0
3    8.0    5.0
4   14.0    6.0
...
```